# android tabcontentfactory and view load events

Tags: android, tabactivity

I an using tabslayout.I choose tabcontentfactory to load views from xml layout.
Like in an activity we have oncreate method which acts as onLoad so that i can fill datasource to various views.

But in tabcontentfactory approach,I can not do this since oncreate has already been fired which is mainly used for creating tabs..
Is there a better way to tell activity that inflated view has been attached to window and now you can use inflated view

Answer (score 2):

It's sounds like you need to inflate views for your tab's content? using tab content factory?  If so, check out this [post from my blog](http://joshclemm.com/blog/?p=59) that seems to do what you want.